# Does a script tag really need a color defined?

Tags: html, javascript, accessibility, colors

I went to achecker.ca to test my website for accessibility issues. While it found no actual problems, it found about 100 potential issues. One of them is this:

```
 1.4 Distinguishable: Make it easier for users to see and 
 hear content including separating foreground from background.

 Success Criteria 1.4.1 Use of Colour (A)

 Check 86: script may use color alone.  Line n, Column n: 

<script async src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

This potential issue refers to all internal and external javascript on my site including google adsense script.

My question is, do I really need to specifically define a default color for such elements or is this tool a joke?

Comment: I can only think that maybe if a script does a `document.write()` and the containing element does not have color defined?! But otherwise this does seem crazy; I've not heard of styling the `script` element itself before?!

Comment: If you do specify a color for the `script` element does this mute the warning? (Or is it actually referring to _something else_?)

Comment: Keep in mind that some of these online sites make too many assumptions and some are a bit crazy. You have to take all of them with serious salt. If you need some, I can send you a supply.

Comment: Well, If these hints make me richer, I'll take them with serious rocks, let alone salt.

Comment: If the checking program doesn't know what your script does (send text to the browser or something else) and/or sees it load before any css info, it can't know if you have set proper (readable) foreground /background combination. So it throws a warning. Just a guess.
Have you set body background-color and color values?

Answer (score 1):

Observations: achecker.ca lists it as "potential problem" (instead of "known" or "likely"). They document this `script` check in http://achecker.ca/checker/suggestion.php?id=86. They seem to justify the problem with guideline [1.4.1 Use of Color](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/#visual-audio-contrast-without-color) from WCAG 2.0.

Let’s see:

1. You could only have a color-related accessibility problem with a `script` element if you *display* this `script` element, for example with the CSS `script {display:block;}`.
2. Assuming that you display the `script` element, you could only fail the WCAG 2.0 guideline *1.4.1 Use of Color* if the `script` element’s color is used for a certain meaning¹ (instead of being pure decoration).
3. Assuming that you use the `script` element’s color for a certain meaning¹, you could only fail that guideline if you don’t provide an alternative² to the color (e.g., text).

A tool can’t possibly check for 2. (if the color has a meaning¹) and 3. (if you provide an alternative²), so it would have to be *always* a potential problem, and for *all* (visible) HTML elements (`script` is nothing special here).

**tl;dr:** Ignore it unless you display the `script` element.

¹ A meaning could be, for example, when refering to the `script` element’s content via its color: "See the JSON in red", "The blue text is authored by Alice", "Additions are green" and so on.

² An alternative could be, for example, when refering to the `script` element’s content via its color and a textual character, an underline, etc. in addition: "See the JSON in red (marked with a `*`)", "The bold blue text is authored by Alice", "Additions are underlined and green" and so on.